# How to find web server slowness with magento website?

Tags: mysql, performance, magento, webserver, database-performance

We have a magento + marketplace website and a good web server by 128G RAM and other hardwares in this level and about 15000 products + not many visitors (about 5000 per days).

BUT we have a trouble on performance.

so...

I would like to know where is our problem?

1- apache webserver? (and we can solve by Engin-X or Litespeed/litemage)

2- mysql many quesries?

3- coding problems?

4- magento is just this!

Is there any webserver monitoring software to see where is exactly our problem?

thanks.

Comment: It could be caused by number of things, the worst nightmare for me was third party extensions. The more I had, the slower the store was. It was due to number of things such as resources used or bad coding practices. Also, what caching do you use? I use Varnish and Redis, I had Amasty FPC but the combination of Redis and Varnish is 100 times better than any extension.

Comment: We use just Redis. I wonder if lite speed + litemage is the best choose or Varnish + Redis?

Comment: I use Varnish as HTTP accelerator, it's designed for HTTP exclusively.  Varnish Cache is really, really fast. It typically speeds up delivery with a factor of 300 - 1000x, depending on your architecture. It works magic. I would recommend Varnish + Redis database. I wouldn't bother with any extensions for performance improvements at all.

Answer (score 0):

yeah. newrelic apm or any other profiler like blackfire.io or tideways.io

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are not effectively using the 128GB.

It could be that you have slow queries.

It could be that Magneto is doing a sloppy job of creating SQL, or what you are telling Magneto leads to sloppy SQL.

Is that 5000 *unique* visitors_ per day?  Or 5000 *visits* per day?

Try to see which of Apache, Magneto, or MySQL is the slow part.

Adding a cache in front of MySQL sometimes slows things down; don't bother.

For more help from the MySQL point of view, follow the steps in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis